# How do I select distinct rows and cross check in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, join, select, union

I have 3 tables, `users` and `tasks` and `completed_tasks`. So basically I want to select all tasks where the `user_id = 2` AND also check that the task does not exist in another table` the So here is my tables:

**`users`** table:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | Sally |
+----+-------+
```

**`tasks`** table:

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | task_name | user_id |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 | mop floor |       2 |
|  2 | dishes    |       1 |
|  3 | laundry   |       2 |
|  4 | cook      |       2 |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

**`completed_tasks`** table:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | task_id | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |       2 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Here is my current `SELECT` code for my MySQL database:

```
$db = "SELECT DISTINCT tasks.task_name, users.name FROM tasks LEFT JOIN ON users.id = tasks.user_id WHERE tasks.user_id = 2";
```

THe problem I'm having is: I want it to search in `completed_tasks` table and if the task exists, then don't select that task.

I tried to do that by adding the following but it did not work:

```
LEFT JOIN completed_tasks ON completed_tasks.user_id = 2
```

That did not work because if I had multiple completed tasks, it would just ignore it all together.

I want the end result should return the user's name and task name of task 3 and 4.

Also, performance is **critical** in my application. I could use PHP and loop through the arrays and do `SELECT` for each of them but that would not be good for performance.

Comment: In the description, there is no `assigned_to` column in your `tasks` table while your query has, do you mean `user_id`?

Comment: @catcon Yes, sorry about that, i edited the post. It should be `user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few ways to do this.

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` and then check for `NULL` in the optional table.

```
SELECT a.name, b.task_name
FROM users a
JOIN tasks b ON a.id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN completed_tasks c ON c.task_id = b.id AND c.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE c.id IS NULL
;
```

You can do a `NOT EXISTS` sub-query

```
SELECT a.name, b.task_name
FROM users a
JOIN tasks b ON a.id = b.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM completed_tasks c
    WHERE c.task_id = b.id AND c.user_id = b.user_id)
;
```

Comment: Thank you, This works but what's the performance like on this compared to other ways of going about this?

Comment: Both will be lightning quick. The database's execution plan is extremely efficient in these types of queries. The worst thing you can do is load partial results into PHP and then execute other queries to get/filter the data. Let the database do this for you in a single query.